# How can I redirect hits to a querystring URL via HTACCESS

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I've created a website with a decent WordPress theme and framework about events but there's some links to a pretty annoying page like this:

```
/?event-category=gigs
```

I would like to redirect any links to URLs like that simply to:

```
/gigs
```

I'm hopeless in Htaccess, can someone suggest the syntax please? I'd appreciate it.

Comment: As you're using Wordpress, you may find it easier to use an SEO Wordpress plugin - https://wordpress.org/plugins/pretty-url/ appears to do what you're after, for example.

Comment: Thank you. I'd still be interested in the syntax though to try and learn.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule just below `RewriteEngine On` line:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)event-category=(gigs) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L,NE]
```